# Unable to install breakpoint in Eclipse: Absent Line Number Information

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic12c

I have a Java 1.6.0 web application that I am developing using a Kepler Version 2 Eclipse development environment.  I am using an Oracle Weblogic Server Administration Console 12c.

I'm running the app locally - and trying to debug it.  Instead of stopping at any of the breakpoints I've set - I get the following error:

[image]

When I installed the application to Weblogic, I ran the Weblogic console and then installed the application by adding the ear file.

I thought I did everything exactly the same as previous web applications I've done this way - but I was always able to debug those applications.

Also - one other thing that is different.  When make any changes and re-build the ear file - I actually have to delete and reinstall from the Weblogic console for the changes to take place.  I'm thinking this might be related.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: have your sources jar attached ? I got this error when I debug on external libraries, after adding source it gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a jar file added to a build path in any of the projects that
include the classes in your project

Comment: Thanks.  So this might be a clueless question - I've already added a number of library jar files to the project.  You're not talking about those, right?  Do I need to create a new jar file that includes all of the classes I've created?

Comment: @TimMitchell How you resolved this issue ? I am getting the same error when try to attaching debug in my app.