# Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attribute

Tags: java, eclipse

When i put breakpoint it show given error:

```
Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attribute
```

I tried most of the option found on stackoverflow still same issue.

[image]

Now same error shows still debugging works fine. Why this error come?

Comment: Did you try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193745/unable-to-install-breakpoint-in-eclipse-absent-line-number-information

Comment: yes but still same issue.

Comment: [this will guide you](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SAPMOB/Unable+to+install+breakpoints%3A+Java+source+code+missing+or+absent+line+numbers+during+Eclipse+Agentry+Editor+debug)

Comment: still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the source code of the class is in a Java project and compiled by Eclipse, do the following:

1. **Right-click on the project** that contains the code and choose ***Properties...***
2. In ***Java Compiler*** check ***Add line number attributes to generated class files (used by the debugger)***

Answer (score 1):

This mostly happens when the project is not built properly (can be due to many issues such as project build properties have not been set properly, build runtime issues, file paths and location reference issues of the source files to the project, etc..). Not only in Eclipse, but in most IDEs, this happens where the line number mapping is not synced with the source code.

I suggest to first check on the build properties and env setup to (clean and) build the project properly, and then try out and see.

Cheers